# Producing a Lucas Series in Lisp

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp, fibonacci

I've just started fiddling with LISP, and I am trying to write a function that produces the Lucas sequence of a given number k. Eventually I want to make this return a list of all the Lucas numbers leading up to this number as well, but for now I want to get the actual calculation of the Lucas number going. I have encountered a problem that I don't know how to overcome, I am trying to have the function return 2 at 0, 1 at 1 and so on, but I keep running into the following error:

I don't know why this is. Please find below my code, any feedback/help would greatly appreciated, as well as any tips in implementing the function of returning a list of all Lucas numbers leading up to the inputted number. Thank you all in advance!

Edit:
error message is >Error(s), warning(s):*** - READ from#<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER#P"1287495122/source.lsp"@6>: an object cannot start with #)

code is:

```
(defun lucas (k)
(if (= k 0))
    2 
(if (= k 1)) 
    k
(+ (lucas (- k 1)) (lucas (- k 2))))) 


(print (lucas 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code has misplaced parentheses, as well as one too many closing parentheses. Correct indentation shows the problem:

```
(defun lucas (k)
  (if (= k 0))
  2
  (if (= k 1))
  k
  (+ (lucas (- k 1)) (lucas (- k 2))))
```

Here there are no expressions to evaluate after the tests in the `if` statements. Instead, `2` should be evaluated if `(= k 0)`, and the second `if` statement should be evaluated otherwise:

```
(defun lucas (k)
  (if (= k 0)
      2
      (if (= k 1)
          k
          (+ (lucas (- k 1)) (lucas (- k 2))))))
```

One could also use `cond` instead of `if` here:

```
(defun lucas-number (n)
  (cond ((= n 0) 2)
        ((= n 1) 1)
        (t
         (+ (lucas-number (- n 1))
            (lucas-number (- n 2))))))
```

You can collect a series of Lucas numbers into a series easily using `loop`:

```
CL-USER> (loop :for n :from 0 :to 10
               :collect (lucas-number n))
(2 1 3 4 7 11 18 29 47 76 123)
```

This iterates `n` from 0 up to and including 10, collecting the associated Lucas numbers in a list. It is easy enough to place this code in a function; here `:below` is used so that the call `(lucas-series 10)` produces the first 10 Lucas numbers instead of all Lucas numbers up to and including that for `n` == 10 (which would be the first 11 Lucas numbers):

```
(defun lucas-series (n)
  (loop :for n :from 0 :below n
        :collect (lucas-number n)))
```

Running this from the REPL:

```
CL-USER> (lucas-series 10)
(2 1 3 4 7 11 18 29 47 76)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As I mentioned I am very new to LISP (just started today) I had no idea indentation was so important, Thank you so much!

Comment: Indentation does not change the meaning of the code (as in Python), but it makes the code much easier to read. The parentheses are what is important, and proper indentation helps you see when something is out of place. A good editor should take care of indentation for you.